# Error: Unauthorized while working with the Youtube Data API

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a web application through which I'd like to be able create playlists, add videos to a playlist, delete a video etc, to my youtube channel. I've followed the example [YouTube API quickstart for nodejs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs) and gotten everything working locally for the past almost 2 weeks but seemingly out of nowhere, I'm getting hit with `Error: Unauthorized`, every time I try to call the API to create a playlist for example.

```
{
  message: 'Unauthorized',
  status: undefined,
  stackHighlighted: 'Error: Unauthorized\n' +
    '    at Gaxios._request (c:\\apps\\node\\myapp\\node_modules\\gaxios\\build\\src\\<mark>gaxios.js:89:23</mark>)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/<mark>task_queues.js:93:5</mark>)\n' +
    '    at async OAuth2Client.requestAsync (c:\\apps\\node\\myapp\\node_modules\\google-auth-library\\build\\src\\auth\\<mark>oauth2client.js:343:18</mark>)\n' +
    '    at async createPlaylist (file:///c:/apps/node/myapp/controllers/youtube.<mark>controller.js:76:22</mark>)'
}
```

Line 76 is where I'm calling `youtube.playlists.insert`.

The only thing that has changed is that I moved the app to a live server, so now both my local copy and the one on the server are both not working. My code basically works like the following.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getChannel);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getChannel(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  service.channels.list({
    auth: auth,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var channels = response.data.items;
    if (channels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No channel found.');
    } else {
      console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                  'it has %s views.',
                  channels[0].id,
                  channels[0].snippet.title,
                  channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
    }
  });
}
```

I don't understand why this is. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: How could have you created playlists when your scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`? According to the official docs, using the `Playlists.insert` endpoint [**requires authorization with at least one**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#auth) of these scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`.

Comment: That's a mistake, the scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`. I've made the edit.

Comment: Could you edit your question for to show the complete error response from the API?

Comment: I've made the edit.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the JSON error response from the API. Could you run a bare `Playlists.insert` call within [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). The goal would be to obtain that JSON response text from the API, which, hopefully, will shed more light on reason why the endpoint call fails.

Comment: Please note that you're able to provide your own credentials (client ID and client secret) via the `OAuth 2.0 Configuration` button located on the top-right corner of the playground page.

Comment: Then you can verify (and also revoke) the permissions granted by your account on the [account's permissions page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions).

Comment: I think I found the problem. At the bottom of the error log I can see `code: 500,
errors: [
 {
    domain: 'youtube.api.v3.PlaylistInsertResponse.Error',
    reason: 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED'
  }
]`. Now what do I do? I filled in the Quota Extension form but the team requires a detailed step by step visual reference of my use case which I cannot provide right now because I'm unable to interact with the API.

Comment: According to [Google staff](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79222309), you only have to wait for a while before you're allowed to create new playlists.

Comment: Thank you for your help mate. It's been almost 48 hours since I started experiencing this issue. I hope a while isn't too long.

Comment: The posters under the question I quoted with my comment above speak about 24 hours; but things change with the API at times without notice. You may [post an inquiry](https://issuetracker.google.com/) yourself, for to see the answer provided by Google staff.